# jekyll minimal mistakes theme throwing "uninitialized constant Faraday::Error::ClientError (NameError)"

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octokit, jekyll-theme

I'm new to using jekyll and tried installing the `minimal-mistakes-jekyll` theme as a gem. Added the gem `minimal-mistakes-jekyll` to my gemfile, updated it with the bundle command, and set it as theme in _config.yml on a directory created by `jekyll new mywebsite` but it's giving me this error when I try to run bundle exec jekyll serve:

`/home/theo/gems/gems/octokit-4.14.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:14:in` `': uninitialised constant Faraday::Error::ClientError (NameError)
Did you mean?  Faraday::ClientError

which persists when I tried using different versions of jekyll. I'm not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated! Running Ubuntu 19.04 and ruby 2.5.5, if that's useful.

Comment: Don't post a link to an external resource showing the steps. Include the steps to reproduce the issue directly in your question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here on MacOS 10.14 / ruby 2.6.3p62

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by editing the `Gemfile` and specifying manually the [0.17.3](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/releases/tag/v0.17.3) version which seams to be the last official release:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
gem 'faraday', '0.17.3'
```

After doing that you'll need to run the following command:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle install
```

Comment: I can confirm this works for a different theme dependent on `faraday`.